# Middleware not executing. Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a middleware that is being called upon a route.

```
router.get('/:endpoint', authController.isLoggedIn, userController.getPages);
```

I need to check if the user isLogged and then call getPages from the userController.

but the isLogged middleware is not doing anything...

```
exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
// first check if the user is authenticated
console.log(res.locals.user)
    if (true) {
      console.log(res.locals.user)
      next(); // carry on! They are logged in!
      return;
    }

  };
```

It should show on the console the value of res.locals.user or undefined, but it doesnt.

Has anyone any idea why is that?

Comment: Provider your endpoint what did you tried.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: How do you test your middleware?

Comment: shouldnt it print what is in the console.log?

Comment: Did you take any http request?

Comment: im using postman to test the requests... the thing is, without that islogged function it all works, I just want to do some stuff using that islogged before the other method is called... but it skips the islogged and I dont know why

Comment: Show me the url what has been used in postman.

Comment: localhost:7777/dashboard

Comment: are you sure `authController.isLoggedIn` links to `exports.isLoggedIn`?

Comment: I have it required on my index.js file.
And I export it from the authController.js file.
I really have no clue what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That was a very stupid mistake I made.

At the very end of my authController.js file I had another definition of isLoggedIn

so as I removed that and left just the one I needed, everything worked as it should.